# References in Visual Studio 2017 changing below the hood

Tags: visual-studio

I've got a bunch of assemblies .dll in a folder. I open a project and add references to those files.

Et voila', Visual Studio copy those dlls into the output folder (Debug/Release/Whatever), change the references so that they point there and...keeps into the prj file the original path.

Result: I update one, some, all the dll, and Visual Studio cannot care less 'cause all it want to use is the local dll. And, to add to the magic, if I do a Rebuild (which does a Clean and then a Build), the references are not valid anymore 'cause the Clean removed the copied file.

Why it's working this way?

Comment: If you are referencing components that are the output of an other VS project, preferably reference the project, not the created output. In any case you can turn off "Copy Local" for those references (see "Properties" of the) to instruct VS not to copy the dll to your projects output folder.

Comment: Referencing other projects it's always been the worst way to do: you are forcing an entire company to structure the network and the code versioning system so that everyone can see everything, plus you are loading in your Visual Studio tens or hundreds of projects you don't need and that just burden down your PC. The Copy Local option does not work because when the software run it doesn't find the dll. Visual Studio should copy local from the original source and keeping a reference to that and keep copying local, instead of copying local once and internally changing the references.

Comment: On second look, it seems you just miss the "Copy Always: true" option to force VS to pull the dlls on *every build* however there is no way to instruct VS to pull references *everytime you run* your project.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I randomly found the answer, it's just a matter of bad settings name.

First of all Visual Studio has an option "Copy Local": you may think that setting this to "No" will do the trick, but it does not work (which is obvious, after you try it) because if he doesn't copy the dll in the output folder then when the software run it doesn't find them (unless we are talking about assemblies in the GAC, but that's a different story).

In itself the problem is that Visual Studio should copy local from the original source and keep a reference to that, instead it copies once in the output folder and from that moment on it internally change the references to the output folder. It still keeps the original references into the prj file, but then it ignore them (so that if you Clean the project or the solution there are no more dll and it doesn't compile anymore)

The solution? The setting labelled as "Specific Version". Despite its name it does not enforce the use of the specific version of the DLL you referenced, it just tell to Visual Studio (coupled with Copy Local=Yes) the equivalent of "Copy Always".